# Why is the 3rd argument not parsed in getopts bash

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I am trying to write a simple script to do something depending on the input arguments. Here is what I have written

```
#!/bin/bash
usage() { echo "Usage: $0 [-l <string>] [-p <string>] [-d <string> ]" 1>&2; exit 1; }

while getopts ":l:p:d" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        l)
            l=${OPTARG}
        echo "$l"
            ;;
        p)
            p=${OPTARG}
        echo "$p"
            ;;
        d)
            d=${OPTARG}
        echo "$d"
            ;;
        *)
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ -z "${l}" ] && [ -z "${p}" ] && [ -z "${d}" ]; then
    usage
fi
```

Its able to parse the inputs given as `-l` and `-p` properly but the third input `-d` is not parsed.

Output:

```
sagar@CPU:~/$ ./play.sh -l "l is parsed" -p "p is parsed" -d "d is parsed"
l is parsed
p is parsed
```

This works

```
sagar@CPU:~/$ ./play.sh -p "p is parsed"
p is parsed
```

Whereas this doesn't work

```
sagar@CPU:~/$ ./play.sh -d "d is parsed"

Usage: ./play.sh [-l <song name>] [-p <song name>] [-d <song name> ]
```

What am I doing wrong here? 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `:` in while statement passing arguments

```
#!/bin/bash
usage() { echo "Usage: $0 [-l <string>] [-p <string>] [-d <string> ]" 1>&2; exit 1; }

while getopts ":l:p:d:" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        l)
            l=${OPTARG}
        echo "$l"
            ;;
        p)
            p=${OPTARG}
        echo "$p"
            ;;
        d)
            d=${OPTARG}
        echo "$d"
            ;;
        *)
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [ -z "${l}" ] && [ -z "${p}" ] && [ -z "${d}" ]; then
    usage
fi
```

**Run :**

```
./script.sh -l "l is parsed" -p "p is parsed" -d "d is parsed"
```

**Output :**

```
l is parsed
p is parsed
d is parsed
```

**Run :**

```
./script.sh -d "d is parsed"
```

**Output :**

```
d is parsed
```